# Vscode debugger will not always show local variables when debugging. Stops after I halt, repeat, or try to debug again after the first time

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, local-variables

Context: I am a student in university that learned how to use debugger a few weeks ago and primarily code in Java/Python. No frameworks yet.

Problem:
I have had a problem with my vscode bugger for quite a while and no one seems to know the answer but the gist is: my debugger won't show local variables when I debug the first time vscode is booted up.  I tried all the relevant possible solutions I found and even went to my professor but even they don't know. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this? Please help.
[image: Correct Debug]
[image: Incorrect Debug]

Main things I tried are:

1. Tried different options to run the debugger (F5, running through "Run and debug" section, etc.)
2. Rebooting vscode every time I needed to debug.
3. Killing terminal and debug session each time.
4. Out of desperation, just printing.

I still am new to programming, so I hope its just an error on my part and that I don't need to move to a different IDE since I really like vscode.

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean `only show local variables when I debug the first time` instead of `won't show local variables when I debug the first time`? Then you need to rebooting vscode every time you need to debug?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your problem, but you can try to clear the cache through the command of `Java:clean Java Language Server Workspace` in the Command Palette(shortcut of **Ctrl+Shift+`**). If it does not work you can try to reinstall the `Debugger for Java` extension, if it still does not work you can try to install the older version of `Debugger for Java` extension.